# Ordenar campos sin importar si es esta en mayúscula o minúscula

Tags: django

Hay alguna manera de decirle a Django que me ordene los campos sin importar si esta en mayúscula o minúscula tengo este modelo:

```
class Mascota(models.Model): 
GENDER_CHOICES = ( 
    ('macho', 'Macho'), 
    ('hembra', 'Hembra'), 
) 
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
tipomascota = models.ForeignKey(TipoMascota, 
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           related_name='mascotas', blank = True) 
raza = models.ForeignKey(Raza, 
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                           related_name='mascotas', blank = True)
sexo = models.CharField(blank = True, max_length=10,  
                          choices=GENDER_CHOICES, 
                          default='macho')                                    
edad = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)

class Meta: 
    ordering = ('nombre',) 

def __str__(self): 
    return self.nombre

def get_absolute_url (self): 
    return reverse('mascota_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

con esta función se ven todos en mayúscula todo pero el orden prioriza las mayúsculas y de ultimo comienza con las minúsculas.

```
class MascotaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('get_nombre', 'edad', 'get_nombre_raza', )
search_fields = ('nombre', 'raza__nombre')  
inlines = [VacunaInline]

def get_nombre(self, obj):
    return ("%s" % (obj.nombre)).upper()    

def get_nombre_raza(self, obj):
    return ("%s" % (obj.raza.nombre)).upper()
get_nombre_raza.admin_order_field  = 'nombre'  #Allows column order sorting
get_nombre_raza.short_description = 'Raza de Mascota'  #Renames column head
```

admin.site.register(Mascota, MascotaAdmin)

La única mascota que su nombre fue introducido en minúscula pero que comienza por la letra "a" me lo pone de ultimo, osea prioriza las mayúsculas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa lo siguiente

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

ordering = (Lower('myfield'),)
```

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias si me sirvio!!!

Comment: @llan Jose Graterol asegúrate de aceptar esta respuesta si es que resolvió tu duda o pregunta.